# Jenkins plugin workspace folder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am writing a plugin for jenkins, and  couldn't find an answer to a simeple question:

> does jenkins provides a folder / workspace that we can count on ?

To be more specific,

If jenkins provide such a folder, how can we access it ?

is there a space limit ? can we count on jenkins to be responsible for that folder ? (so jenkins won't delete / clean it)

Any help would be great ! (I couldn't find much information about it, so links will be helpful to)

Thanks!

Comment: Is that a folder for the job which is building? or a folder for things to do with the plugin to go?

Comment: let's say it's a folder to do things with the plugin to go.. the build folder is temporary.. so i can't count on it.. from what i understand..